# Can I prevent text highlight when I hit "return" keystroke on a NSTextField?

Tags: macos, nstextfield

Before I hit "return" keystroke:

[image]

After I hit "return" keystroke:

[image]

I don't want that highlight, just want to keep it unchanged.
How can I do that?

Here is the code snippet for this text field:

```
let searchField = NSTextField()   
searchField.isBezeled = false
searchField.drawsBackground = false
searchField.textColor = .white
searchField.focusRingType = .none
searchField.usesSingleLineMode = true
searchField.cell?.sendsActionOnEndEditing = false
searchField.target = self
searchField.action = #selector(searchAction)
```

Edit: Seems like it's just highlight but not a selection,because

```
let textEditor = window?.fieldEditor(true, for: searchField)

textEditor.selectedRange.length == 0 //length is 0
```

Comment: Do you want to end editing and send the action? Do you want to select the text if the user tabs into the field? When do you look at the selection?

Comment: 1: Yes, it will send action when user hit "return" keystroke;
2: No;
3: selection is not important in this case, when user hit return, my app just get current text and use it as a keyword for requesting some data.

Comment: It's not just highlight, it is the selection.

Comment: If it is a selection, how can I undo it? That selection effect just doesn't fit in my app's interface design.

Comment: Similar question: [Prevent selecting all tokens in NSTokenField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995205/prevent-selecting-all-tokens-in-nstokenfield/3008622#3008622). There are other workarounds like overriding `selectText:` and setting the selection back.