# NSOutlineView: How to pre-select a specific portion of a cell's text when editing?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

I have a Cocoa app with an `NSOutlineView` (view-based) showing a directory tree very much like Finder.

Basic cell editing works, i.e. I can select a cell representing a file and press Return to edit its name.

Now I'd like to pre-select the file name excluding the file extension like in this example:

[image: Finder example]

However, by default, everything in the text field is selected. How can I select only a specific portion of the value?

I could not figure out how to intercept when editing a table cell view begins to set the selection. I made my outline view the delegate of the `NSTextField` in the `NSTableCellView`, but `control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText)` and `controlTextDidBeginEditing()` are only called when the user types the first letter.

Again, my outline view is view-based. What am I missing here?

Comment: Similar questions: [Prevent selecting all tokens in NSTokenField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995205/prevent-selecting-all-tokens-in-nstokenfield/3008622#3008622) and [Can I prevent text highlight when I hit “return” keystroke on a NSTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977719/can-i-prevent-text-highlight-when-i-hit-return-keystroke-on-a-nstextfield)

Comment: Could you switch to using NStextView instead, set to plain-text and single line? NSTextViewDelegate gives you a lot of control here.